# Best Approach to using Top and Count - SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have an 2008 C# application (back end SQL Server 2008) where sometimes queries return a large number of results.  So, I researched some paging algorithms and put one in place that uses the TOP statement.  I love the fact that if I have 500 total results and am only showing 20 results per page that I can only query the database for 20 records instead of storing all 500 records in memory.

The issue I have though is that in order to implement the paging algorithm, I need to know how many total records there are in this query.  So, what I have done is to just run another query with the same parameters that just selects the ID (instead of the whole object) to try to make it run quickly.  For some reason though, I think that running these two queries (thus establishing 2 connections) isn't the best approach.

So I need the count of *all* of the records but only want to select the limited number used in TOP.  Would a temporary table be of use here?  I have two different stored procedures now.

Thanks for any "best practices" advice anyone can give.

Answer (score 0):

You could use object datasource...to implement this custom paging.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...)`. More details [here](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/12/30/2652.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what approach that you are taking for paging however the technique that I usually use is to use the `ROW_NUMBER` function, for example:

```
SELECT  Description, Date
FROM
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date DESC) AS Row,
        Description, Date 
    FROM Log
) AS LogWithRowNumbers
WHERE  Row >= 1 AND Row <= 10
```

This approach is the cleanest that I am aware of, works with any subquery and only requires a single query.

Of course if you wish to show a "total hits" or similar on your page then you will also need another query to get the row count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Log
```

However you can execute both statements in the same batch to prevent the need for an extra "round trip" to the databse server.

Source - [Paging Records Using SQL Server 2005 Database - ROW_NUMBER Function](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/12/30/2652.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I have used the ROW_NUMBER() in the Stored Procedure that gets the count.  And for that I use ExecuteScalar(); in C#.  For the Stored Procedure that uses Top I am filling a dataset (.Fill(ds);)   I guess I'm not sure how I'd get both to return from one Stored Procedure.  But then once I have the Count, wouldn't that be running the Count query again unnecessarily because from there all I would need would be the TOP query?  Thanks!

Comment: @PTVee Running a separate count query isn't really *unneccessary* as you can't get this information from your main paging query (whatever method you choose) - The best you could get from your main paging query is the size of the current page.  Besides, a count query is usually fairly quick.

Comment: OK, Bob answered my question above about running both in the same Stored Procedure.  I appreciate all of the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you perform both selects within your stored proceedure you would get two datatables in your dataset after using the Fill method.

Comment: Ahhh!!  OK, I could try that!!  Thanks!!

Comment: Then perhaps my app could determine if I don't need the Count for subsequent pages (since I already have it), so I could test for that and then just run the SP that just gets the TOP records.  Just thinking out loud here.

Comment: Yes, but what do you want to do if a record is added/removed by another user inbetween page requests?

Comment: Hmmmm?  I guess that's true, it would only be one or two records that could possibly come in, but then the paging could be inaccurate.

Comment: Hi Bob, worked great!  I put both of the Selects in one stored procedure and the second Select fill(ed) into the dataset.  So, while I still am running both queries, I've eliminated the two round trips.  Thanks to all helping here.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date DESC) AS Row,
        COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalCount,
        Description, Date 
    FROM Log
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE Row BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

This will provide both paging and a count in 1 query.  You could also use a CASE statement to only do the count at certain times.  For instance does the count change while users are paging through?

Comment: Thats possibly less efficient that two queries because you are returning count multiple times, also not sure if the query optimizer wouldn't re-peform the count for every row

Comment: That is possible.  In our app we use CASE statement and a flag to control when we do the count.